# POST request with multipart/mixed (not multipart/form-data) content-type and boundary string in React App running in browser using Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, multipart

I need to create a POST request with **multipart/mixed** (not multipart/form-data) content-type and **boundary string** in React App.

```
--boundary-string
Content-Disposition: name="request_payload"
Content-Type: text/xml
<tsRequest>
  <workbook name="workbook-name" showTabs="show-tabs-flag" thumbnailsUserId="user-luid">
    <connections>
    <connection serverAddress="server-address" serverPort="port-number">
    <connectionCredentials name="connection-username" password="connection-password"
          embed="embed-flag" />
    </connection>
    </connections>
    <project id="project-id"/>
  </workbook>
</tsRequest>
--boundary-string
Content-Disposition: name="tableau_workbook"; filename="workbook-file-name"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
--content-of-workbook-file--
--boundary-string--
```

So request should consist of two parts:

1. XML fragment
2. File

Lets assume that my XML fragment is saved in string variable:

```
const xml: string = '...my xml...'
```

And content of my file is saved in ArrayBuffer variable:

```
const fileContent: ArrayBuffer = ...
```

Content-Type of the whole request should be:

```
"Content-Type": `multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundaryString}`
```

How to construct this POST request using Axios?

Comment: have you read any [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart)

Comment: This documentation is about multipart/form-data and it doesn't say anything about multipart/mixed and boundary string

Comment: So assemble that body content in string form, and pass that for the `data` parameter. And set the Content-Type header.

Comment: ahh,seems it's been [asked here](https://github.com/axios/axios/discussions/5588) and no solution found

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

In Node.js (not in Browser) I was able to achive this using libraries:

```
"form-data": "^4.0.0",
"axios": "^1.3.4",
```

```
const FormData = require("form-data");
const Axios = require("axios");    

class MyFormData extends FormData {
  toString() {}
}
const form = new MyFormData();

const xml: string = "...my xml...";
const fileContent: ArrayBuffer = ...;

form.append("request_payload", xml, {
  contentType: "application/xml",
});

form.append("tableau_workbook", fileContent, {
  filename: "workbook-file-name.twb",
  contentType: "application/octet-stream",
});

const axiosClient = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://...",
});

await axiosClient.post("sites/:siteId/workbooks", form, {
  headers: {
    ...form.getHeaders(),
    "Content-Type": `multipart/mixed; boundary=${form.getBoundary()}`,
  },
});
```